# How do I set a value to a UserContext.Provider with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to set a default value to my `UserContext.Provider` and printed it in a simple div. I am using 2 pages in this little test, `Info.js`, `UserContext.js`

```
// UserContext.js

import { createContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext('');

export default UserContext ;
```

```
// Info.js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import UserContext from './UserContext'

function Info (){
    const msg = useContext(UserContext)
    console.log(msg)
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={'user'}>
            <div>
                hello {msg}

            </div>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default Info
```

The only thing I get is the "hello" in the div. If I change the default value in `createContext('')` to something like `createContext('user')` in the `info.js` will return `"hello user"` but I want to set the value in value property of `UserContext.Provider`.

Comment: How is your provider configured? You need a function that handles the state inside your context.how are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: but i dont have a state i just want to print the value that i give to the provider ... if that make sense or i am just using it wrong because i am new to react and use context hook

Comment: Remember when you call ´´´´useContext()´´´´ this returns the **state** ( or the value that you passed ) and a **method** to update the same or in the case the reducer. So maybe you need to receive an array and not a single value : 

````const [msg , updateMessage ] = useContext(UserContext)````. And If you just need a value why dont you just pass it as a prop?

Comment: Because i want to learn how to use createContext hook and i want to start by doing something easy like this . it would be helpful if  you have any link or something i can read or watch for createContext hook too .